# Are CKQuery string comparisons actually case insensitive?

Tags: swift, nspredicate, cloudkit

As per the `CKQuery` docs

"String-based comparisons are case insensitive but otherwise all comparisons must be an exact match of the specified value."

I haven't found this to be the case. IE my predicate *is* indeed case sensitive. My searches are failing for a given record "My Record" when searching "my record"

```swift
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", title)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: .song, predicate: predicate)
```

Has anyone come across this? Can anyone provide a method of explicitly ensuring a predicate is case insensitive?

Answer (score 1):

As per this [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1) by Apple (String Comparisons section):

> String comparisons are, by default, case and diacritic sensitive. You
> can modify an operator using the key characters c and d within square
> braces to specify case and diacritic insensitivity respectively.

If you must `match the keyword` but the search must be `case-insensitive` then you should use:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "keywords.name =[c] %@", title)
```